# How to limit or improve comparison between tables?

Tags: mysql

Although the SQL query seems to work for the most part, my attempt to use an EXISTS condition to "limit the comparison set to records containing one of the field1 values from the import only" does not seem to be applying and so I am affecting records which should be ignored in the queries.  Can someone give me a bit of guidance on making these queries better?

Given: two tables in a MySQL database: "t.import" and t.main"

First Goal: Insert records present in t.import and missing from t.main:

```
INSERT INTO t.main (field1,field2,field3)
SELECT field1,field2,field3
FROM t.import
WHERE 
    ((field1,field2,field3) NOT IN (SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM t.main))
AND
    (field1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT field1 FROM t.import AS field1 ORDER BY field1));
```

Second goal: Mark records in t.main if there is no matching record from t.import BUT only if the t.main record contains one of the various values from field1 in t.import

```
UPDATE t.main SET field3 = 'Dead'
WHERE (field1,field2,field3)
NOT IN (SELECT field1,field2,field3
  FROM t.import)
      AND
  (field1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT field1 FROM t.import AS field1 ORDER BY field1))      
      AND
  field1 != 0;
```

Comment: I'd think that `AND EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT field1 FROM t.import)` should be rewritten in the same way as the condition prior to it:  `AND field1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT field1 FROM t.import)`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my original code and it seems to work better, but it is still VERY slow.  Any suggestions?  Is "IN" and "NOT IN" the best/fastest way to make comparisons?

Comment: Maybe see about JOINs?